# Codeigniter extend form validation not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-2, extend

For the past hours I have tried to extend the form validation library in Codeigniter 2.2.0 with a rule, but it does not seem to get it at all? It just continues, like the rule doesn not exist at all.

My extension of the form validation is located in application/libraries and is named MY_Form_validation.php.

The file contains the following code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    public function run($module = '', $group = '')
    {
        (is_object($module)) AND $this->CI =& $module;
        return parent::run($group);
    }

    public function price_validation($str)
    {
        if (!preg_match('/^\d+(?:\,\d{1,2})?$/', $str))
        {
            $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('price_validation', 'Feltet %s må kun indeholde tal, ét komma og to decimaler.');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
/* End of file MY_Form_validation.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php */
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: missing __constructor, create one and pass it some $config as paremeter

Comment: Like so? public function __construct($config)
 {
        parent::__construct($config);
 } Because that's not working, and to be honest I'm not sure if I man doing it right.

Comment: It seems not to be loading it at all. If I make an error, it is not showing up at all. I am autoloading the form validation library in my autoload config file. Should not Codeigniter by itself find my extension of the library in libraries/MY_Form_validation.php when my prefix in config is set to MY_

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I have made an typo in the filename. Which I thought I have checked out. Not a proud moment.